# Linux picking wrong source IP

Tags: amazon-ec2, iproute, kubernetes

I have an EC2 instance running on a k8s cluster. The instance has three three interface cards.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:9c:bb:70:ee:be brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.206/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 2821sec preferred_lft 2821sec
---
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:7a:d4:ac:64:b4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::7a:d4ff:feac:64b4/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:54:4e:b4:b4:e8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.6.4/24 brd 10.0.6.255 scope global dynamic eth2
       valid_lft 2863sec preferred_lft 2863sec
    inet6 fe80::54:4eff:feb4:b4e8/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

*Please ignore eth1 as not yet configured correctly.*

When I ping (`ping -I 10.0.6.4 www.google.com`) from eth2 to internet, I notice that linux picks the primary interfaces's IP

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-2-206 ~]$ sudo tcpdump -i eth2 -n
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
14:19:08.968772 IP 10.0.2.206 > 142.251.42.36: ICMP echo request, id 17679, seq 9, length 64
14:19:09.992871 IP 10.0.2.206 > 142.251.42.36: ICMP echo request, id 17679, seq 10, length 64
14:19:11.016767 IP 10.0.2.206 > 142.251.42.36: ICMP echo request, id 17679, seq 11, length 64
```

As you can see the source IP is incorrectly selected as `10.0.2.206` instead of `10.0.6.4`.

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-2-206 ~]$ ip rule
0:      from all lookup local
511:    from 10.0.6.4 lookup 10002
512:    from all to 10.0.2.4 lookup main
512:    from all to 10.0.2.185 lookup main
512:    from all to 10.0.2.233 lookup main
1024:   from all fwmark 0x80/0x80 lookup main
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

[ec2-user@ip-10-0-2-206 ~]$ sudo ip route show table 10002
default via 10.0.6.1 dev eth2 src 10.0.6.4
10.0.6.0/24 dev eth2 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.6.4

[ec2-user@ip-10-0-2-206 ~]$ sudo ip route show table main
default via 10.0.2.1 dev eth0
default via 10.0.6.1 dev eth2 metric 10002
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.206
10.0.2.4 dev eni379b345d249 scope link
10.0.2.185 dev eni0231b3becdb scope link
10.0.2.233 dev eni5be9f7773c7 scope link
10.0.6.0/24 dev eth2 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.6.4
169.254.169.254 dev eth0

[ec2-user@ip-10-0-2-206 ~]$ ip route get 172.217.174.68 from 10.0.6.4
172.217.174.68 from 10.0.6.4 via 10.0.6.1 dev eth2 table 10002 uid 1000
    cache
```

All config seems to be correct but source address is still picked up from primary interface. What am I missing?

Comment: IP address will be the IP of the interface where the packet leaves to the gateway, per your routing

Answer (score 1):

The one place I did not look *carefully* is iptables. I found the following entries in it.

```
Chain AWS-SNAT-CHAIN-0 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
AWS-SNAT-CHAIN-1  all  --  anywhere            !ip-10-0-0-0.xxxx.compute.internal/16  /* AWS SNAT CHAIN */

Chain AWS-SNAT-CHAIN-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
SNAT       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* AWS, SNAT */ ADDRTYPE match dst-type !LOCAL to:10.0.2.206 random-fully
```

Searching further, I found AWS documentation on the subject: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/external-snat.html

As per documentation when I executed the command `kubectl set env daemonset -n kube-system aws-node AWS_VPC_K8S_CNI_EXTERNALSNAT=true`, the `SNAT` entries were removed from the VMs.

Once that was done, pings from eth2 showed correct source IP - `10.0.6.4`.